# Make background image move when you move the page

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make the background image move when you scroll the page up and down, whenever i scroll up and down the background image stays still but I want it to move with the page, is that possible?

Comment: By default a background image *should* scroll with the page.  Why don't you show a minimal code example to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: i dont understand two things: 1. image stays still? 2. move with the page?

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the attachment to `fixed`.

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

If you have a large image, you can use `background-size`. 
For example:

```
html {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}-
```

`background-size` does what it tells you. Using `cover` as the attribute, the background image is scaled to fill the entire background, thus getting rid of the scrollbars when using an image larger than your screen.

Answer (score 1):

[background-attachment](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/properties/colorbg/bgattach.htm)?

Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment